# Assembly , interrupt #21 , 4eh , 4fh problem !

Tags: assembly, file, dos, root, interrupt

Can some one tell me how I can use these functions?
int 21h , 4eh , 4fh (**in MS Dos** )

I wanna list files and directories ... how should I do that?

I wish some one could give me a source code or an example of int21h 4eh/4fh ..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Almost all libraries/platforms have better methods to get the files. What are programming in/for?

Comment: I know , but i got to use assembly. i need it for an academic project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm...now here's some ancient code:

```
.model small, c

.stack

.data
    file_spec db "*.*", 0
    DTA db 128h dup(0)

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @Data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx,offset DTA
    mov ah,1Ah
    int 21h

    mov dx,offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah,4Eh
    int 21h
    jc  quit

print_name:
    lea si, DTA + 1eh
next_char:
    lodsb
    int 29h
    test al, al
    jnz next_char

    mov al, 13
    int 29h
    mov al, 10
    int 29h

    mov dx, offset file_spec
    xor cx, cx
    mov ah, 4fh
    int 21h
    jnc print_name
quit:   
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
main endp
    end main
```

As you can see, in my younger days, I *really* believed in lots of comments (though, I have to admit that even looking at it now, it doesn't seem particularly difficult to follow).

Answer (score 2):

Function 4eh finds the first file matching some attributes, which are stored in `cx` according to the following scheme:

```
bit 0 = 1 read-only file
bit 1 = 1 hidden file
bit 2 = 1 system file
bit 3 = 1 volume (ignored)
bit 4 = 1 reserved (0) - directory
bit 5 = 1 archive bit
bits 6-15 reserved (0)
```

`ds:dx` should contain the address of the (null terminated) filename (wildchars allowed). So for example to list all exes in c:\ the filename will be `c:\*.exe`.
On return, if the carry flag is set to 1 there weren't files, otherwise the DTA is filled in this way:

```
Offset   Size in bytes   Meaning

0        21              Reserved
21       1               File attributes
22       2               Time last modified
24       2               Date last modified
26       4               Size of file (in bytes)
30       13              File name (ASCIIZ)
```

You can tell DOS where you want the DTA to be placed with this simple snippet:

```
mov dx,OFFSET youChoose     ; DS:DX points to DTA 
mov ah,1AH               ; function 1Ah - set DTA
int 21h                     ; call DOS service
```